# not receiving events with this basic socket.io + redis setup?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I've got a simple socket.io server using socket.io-redis, an socket.io-emitter, and I run redis (which is completely new to me, I'm on windows, I downloaded redis and opened redis-server.exe and redis-cli.exe).
Through the redis CLI with the command `monitor` I see that the server is connected and that events reach redis from the emitter, but `test-server.js` never logs anything. What else do I need to do? Does the socket.io server need to subscribe to redis?

Redis output `"publish" "socket.io#/#" "\x93\xa7emitter\x83\xa4type\x02\xa4data\x92\xa4test\xa9some data\xa3nsp\xa1/\x82\xa5rooms\x90\xa5flags\x80"`

**test-server.js**

```
var server = require('http').Server();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');

io.adapter(redis({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379 }));
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('client connected'); // Works
    socket.emit('connect','test'); // Works
});
io.on('test', function(socket){
    console.log('test came in'); // Works
});
server.listen(3000);
```

**test-emit.js**

```
var io = require('socket.io-emitter')({
    host:'localhost',
    port:'6379'
});
setInterval(function(){
    io.emit('test', 'some data');
    console.log('emitted');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is that `socket.io-emitter` was not what I needed for this test case.
It connects directly to redis. In the example below I now use the usual `socket.io-client` and all events properly arrive in the server, and also with two servers and two clients connected each to a different server, with `io.emit` both clients now recieve the event. Great!

**test-emit.js**

```
var PORT = 3000;
var HOST = 'http://localhost';
var port = parseInt(process.argv[2]) || PORT;
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect(HOST + ':' + port);

socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connected, sending message');
    socket.emit('message', 'message from client');
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        console.log('new message received: '+data);
    });
});
```

**test-server.js**

```
var port = parseInt(process.argv[2]) || 3000;
console.log('server listens on port ' + port);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(port);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
var adapter = redis({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379 });
io.adapter(adapter);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('client connected');
    io.emit('message', 'client logged in on '+port+' and this message will be send to all clients');
    socket.on('message', function(d){
        console.log('message from socket:',d);
    });
});
```

start 4 different terminals and run:

```
$ node test-server 3000
$ node test-server 3001
$ node test-emit 3000
$ node test-emit 3001
```

Comment: I am also using Redis to serve messages via socket.io-redis. My app is woking as I expected. But when I examine the data in the Redis dbs using redis-cli , I could not see any messages there. Why is that?

Comment: @Niroshana no data is stored on redis itself, but you can use PSUBSCRIBE * or MONITOR to watch incoming data: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis-adapter/#how-does-it-work-under-the-hood